# sharepoint append emails to a page

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I would like to collect emails in a SharePoint page, appending them to a dedicated page of a users daily emails. I have email enabled libraries working, but what we really want is one page displaying email content not in a library but in a page.
Is this a simple SP Webpart function, or a Foreach loop in Designer?

Is there a simple way to do this in SharePoint or do I need to do something with JavaScript or JQUERY, loop through my source library and write the HTML to my page?

My data is a collection of .EML files.

Heck, I can easily Display A file via simple JavaScript function using:
window.location.assign("My_FILE_NAME.EML");
What's good a way to loop and Append these files in A SharePoint page ?
And, VIA sharepoint, can I manipulate/enter JS in a page, or do I gotta do it via SP Designer?

Comment: By collecting e-mail, do you mean getting e-mail data from users?

Comment: yes, i'm collecting a daily email from 1 user into a library and would like to have them all display in a page, appended. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web part do this or you can create a custom list in SharePoint and then let your users add new entries and display them in a page easily. Here is a [walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmVy5roiKzg) how to create a custom list in SharePoint.

**UPDATED:**

One way to do that is, you can [create an **Event Receiver**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) for your library and create a Web Part to display the appended e-mails.

User adds an .eml file to your library. On overridden`ItemAdd` method in your **Event Receiver** you can parse this file and maybe insert this e-mail to table in a database or to a custom list. Then you can display this list/table content in a GridView/Table in a simple Web Part.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't think that will create what I need. I have a collection of .EML files I want to display/appended. But I will look again at your suggestion..